# The Spring url to get all request mappings does not work (anymore)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Usually I could get a url mapping overview using the url:
`/application/mappings`

Now I get a
`PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/application/mappings]` in my log and `Response Status: 404 (Not Found)` in my browser.

Also the other Spring urls `/application/autoconfig, /application/beans and /application/configprops` give the same problem.

I'm using spring-boot 2.0.0.RELEASE.

The actuator artifact was added to the pom:

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have different management.context-path defined that overrides the default "application" ?

Comment: We can't answer your question without seeing the actual code example you wrote.. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your answer accordingly. :)

Comment: I have nothing overridden or specified in my application property file.

Answer (score 0):

According to the current Spring Boot 2.0 [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) the default actuator endpoints are prefixed with `/actuator`, not with `/application`. This was different for [M4](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M4/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready) and I think they've changed it in [M7](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready).

M4 docs:

> For example, by default, the health endpoint will be mapped to
>   /application/health.

M7 docs:

> For example, by default, the health endpoint is mapped to
>   /actuator/health